# How to call-process to start emacs inside emacs, with parameters

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like emacs to process some time-consuming tasks, without blocking input. For this purpose, I tried (where the insert is meant to be replaced by the time-consuming task)

```
(call-process "emacs" nil 0 nil "--eval=(insert \"a\")")
```

This works. However, when I want to pass a frame parameter, it doesn't work:

```
(call-process "emacs" nil 0 nil "--geometry 30x5")
```

Emacs says "Unknown option `--geometry 30x5".

Any ideas to use call-process to start another emacs session with refined frame size? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using `call-process`, each argument to the program being started must be in a separate string - spaces don't count as separators.  Your first example works, because it's a single argument, but the second example requires two parameters and should be written like this:

```
(call-process "emacs" nil 0 nil "--geometry" "30x5")
```

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you might want [async.el](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async), which does indeed run additional instances of Emacs to carry out the specified processing.

(although I'm unsure of your requirement for a visible frame.)

Follow the link for details of all the other functionality on offer, but the simplest usage example given (which seemed like it might be applicable) is:

```el
(async-start
   ;; What to do in the child process
   (lambda ()
     (message "This is a test")
     (sleep-for 3)
     222)

   ;; What to do when it finishes
   (lambda (result)
     (message "Async process done, result should be 222: %s" result)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is very interesting to know this package! I will give it a try.